# file layout breaking after convert xlsx into pdf file using libreoffice

Tags: node.js, bash, libreoffice

In my project. I have a requirement in which I need to convert xlsx file into pdf file.
I'm using LibreOffice. but libreoffice is breaking my xlsx file layout after converting into pdf.
this is command I'm using.

```
libreoffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore  --convert-to pdf "Example Spreadsheet.xlsx"
```

Any solution

Comment: Sorry, what kind of solution do you expect? The command is written correctly, I think that LibreOffice is doing it as needed. Are you saying that the file layout of your xlsx is breaking? How strong is breaking? Everything looks good in the attached screenshot.

Comment: actually, I want in pdf view.  all the columns in xlsx file display in a single table like in xlsx file. but that's not happening. LibreOffice applying line break. due to which some of the columns displaying in the next line in pdf view.  @JohnSUN

Comment: Thanks, clearer. Do you have the option to open the original file in Excel? Please look at the settings in three places - Print area (set), Page size and in File-Print the lowest Scale setting. Perhaps you have these items called differently, I translated from localized menu items. Now save your workbook and try converting it again.